# Consquences of changing Android minSdkVersion 15 to 19

Tags: android, alarmmanager

My project has `minSdkVersion 15`, but I need to use the `AlarmManager.setExact()` function, which requires `minSdkVersion 19`.

My question is: what could be the consequences of changing from 15 to 19?

Am I going to loose possible app users?
If yes, then how many?
And is there any workaround?

Comment: that is a good suggestion, only thing is that if I use set() the alarm will run every time while if I use setExact() it will run only once at that exact time, is that right?

Comment: No, that's wrong. `set()` only fires once. For repeating alarms you use `setRepeating()`.

Comment: oh that is great, one more thing, why not use set() always instead of setExact() for >19 ? what is wrong with using set() only?

Comment: ok, now I get everything. I should use set() for targetSdkVersion<19 and setExact() for 19+. And both will use same calling arguments and will result in same behaviour. please post you answer so I can accept, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: **don't** switch (you don't want to loose your pontential customers).
Just check if the OS version is <19, then use `set()`.
Otherwise, use `setExact()`. That's all.

The reason you need to use `setExact()` is that

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use.
>   There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent).
>   Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

from the [reference docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: javadoc mentions targetSdkVersion and you told to compare API level i.e. SDK_INT. What should be compared actually?

Comment: `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK` gives you the current API Level

Comment: I knew. But javadocs mentions to compare targetSdkVersion and we are comparing SDK_INT. Strange!! SDK_INT and targetSdkVersion are different things.

Comment: You don't have to be concerned with the targetSdkVersion. You just want to know your **current** API Level (the one the current device is using).